# Django project documentation with sphinx

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I'm using django 1.5.8 and Sphinx 1.2.2 with autodoc enabled. I've added some code to `conf.py`:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
print sys.path

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

from django.conf import settings
```

but when I'm trying to make documentation, autodoc fails on each file that imports django.db.models with error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

`SECRET_KEY` is defined on my settings.py file (without that my app wouldn't run at all and also sphinx will fail on processing conf.py file).

Comment: can you show us where and how is your `SECRET_KEY` defined in your `settings.py` file?

Comment: It's just in `project/settings.py` file: `SECRET_KEY = 'q_VERY_SECRET_c'`. Nothing tricky here, and as I mentioned before, application works fine, just `make html` for Sphinx is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange...

Problem disappears when I changed value of secret key.